# Testing conditional Bean creation with @ConditionalOnProperty and @FeignClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-test, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Rest Controller, a Service and a Feign Client being used inside the service.
Now, I need to conditionally create the controller bean based on an environment variable. I have been able to set up the configuration and it looks like it should work. So far so good. But I am having a hard time testing the conditional bean creation.

The REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/path")
public class AbcController {
  private final AbcService abcService;
  
  @Autowired
  public AbcController(AbcService abcService) {
    this.abcService = abcService;
  }
  ...
}
```

The Service:

```
@Service
public class AbcService {
  private final AbcClient abcClient;

  @Autowired
  public AbcService(AbcClient abcClient) {
    this.abcClient = abcClient;
  }
```

Feign Client:

```
@Component
@FeignClient(name = "abc", url = "${abc.url}", decode404 = true)
public interface AbcClient {
  @RequestMapping(
    value = "/match",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
  )
  MatchResponse getSsoIds(RequestDto requestDto);
}
```

Configuration for conditionally loading the Controller class:

```
@Configuration
public class AbcConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(
    value="feature.enabled",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = true
  )
  public AbcController abcController(AbcService abcService) {
    return new AbcController(abcService);
  }
}
```

The Test class for testing the conditional bean creation:

```
public class AbcControllerTest {

  private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
    .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(AbcConfiguration.class));

  @Test
  public void loadsControllerBeanWhenPropertyIsEnabled() {
    this.contextRunner
      .withPropertyValues("feature.enabled=true")
      .run(context -> context.assertThat().hasSingleBean(AbcController.class));
  }

  @Test
  public void loadsControllerBeanWithoutDefinedProperty() {
    this.contextRunner
      .run(context -> context.assertThat().hasSingleBean(AbcController.class));
  }

  @Test
  public void doesNotLoadControllerBeanWhenPropertyIsDisabled() {
    this.contextRunner
      .withPropertyValues("feature.enabled=false")
      .run(context -> context.assertThat().doesNotHaveBean(AbcController.class));
  }
}
```

I have tried to run the test but the first 2 tests always ends up complaining about missing or non-configurable beans. The last test runs as expected.

With the above test setup it complains about missing AbcService bean, which we can solve by adding

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AbcService.class)
```

to the top of the test class, but then it complains `No qualifying bean of type 'de.xxx.xxx.AbcClient'` and we cannot create a bean of the feignClient AbcClient because it is an interface.

Help needed! How to make these tests pass?

Comment: You need `@EnableFeignClients` somewhere

Comment: That's not the problem. It's added already. I was able to reach to a solution, will post the answer soon.